# JUnit setUp method test state variables best practices

Tags: java, junit

Are there any rules or best practices for the `setUp` method for JUnit tests - specifically around defining test state variables.

For example, if some state variable X is not used in all tests, should it still be initialized in the `setUp` method (and defined as a `private` member variable in the test class)? Or should it be defined in the test methods where it is used? If the `setUp` method is used as an "initializer" for variables that may be used in some subset of the test methods, how do you keep the `setUp` method clean for larger service classes that may have more interactions than other / smaller components.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my opinionated best practices:

1. There is no setUp() method.  If you use the @Before annotation (junit 4), the method name should be `before`.  If you use the @BeforeEach annotation (junit 5), the method name shold be `beforeEach`.
2. Create all mock objects via the @Mock annotation.
3. If using Junit 4, call `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)` as the first "thing" in the `before` method.
4. Don't use Junit 4, if you can.  Instead use Junit 5.
5. If using Junit 5, annotate the class with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`
6. Name the thing-that-is-being-tested "classToTest".
7. If not using @InjectMocks, instantiate the classToTest object in the `before` method.
8. Perform manual mock injection (for example, mock a non-injected logger) in the `before` method.
9. Use `doReturn(xxx).when(xxx).xxx()`.
10. Avoid `when(xxx.xxx()).thenReturn(xxx)`.
11. If 100% of your test methods will "use" one stubbed method, stub it in the before method.
12. For all other stubbing, perform stubbing in each test.
13. If many (you determine the number) tests require the same stubbing, create a private method to perform the stubbing and call it in the tests where such stubbing is required.